# download zipped csv from url and convert to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, download, zip

I want to download and read a file from this site: http://data.gdeltproject.org/events/index.html

each of the files are of the named `YYYYMMDD.export.CSV.zip`

I am stuck at this point in my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import zipfile
import requests
from datetime import date, timedelta  
url = 'http://data.gdeltproject.org/events/index.html'
yesterday = (date.today() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y%m%d')
file_from_url = yesterday + '.export.CSV.zip'
with open(file_from_url, "wb") as f: 
    f.write(resp.content)
```

now I am stuck trying to read the contents

I tried readlines, but this did not work

Any suggestions how I can read my zipped file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First issue is the `url` variable is defined but never used

```py
url = 'http://data.gdeltproject.org/events/index.html'
```

The `index.html` part of the `url` is of no use when downloading the zipped CSV files -- you need to construct a url string like this `http://data.gdeltproject.org/events/20230412.export.CSV.zip`. Something like this is what you need

```py
from datetime import date, timedelta  

base_url = 'http://data.gdeltproject.org/events/'
yesterday = (date.today() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y%m%d')
filename = yesterday + '.export.CSV'
url = base_url + filename + ".zip"
print(f'URL is "{url}"')
```

that outputs this for me

```
URL is "http://data.gdeltproject.org/events/20230412.export.CSV.zip"
```

Next, you are not downloading anything from `data.gdeltproject.org`. Your code, below, is attempting to open a local file for writing

```py
with open(file_from_url, "wb") as f: 
    f.write(resp.content)
```

You need to download the file file and open that for reading. Something like this should do the trick

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from datetime import date, timedelta  

base_url = 'http://data.gdeltproject.org/events/'
yesterday = (date.today() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y%m%d')
filename = yesterday + '.export.CSV'
url = base_url + filename + ".zip"

r = requests.get(url)

# Create a dataframe from the CSV data
# CSV is tab-separated and doesn't have a header row 
df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(r.content), compression='zip', delimiter='\t', header=None)

print(df.head())
```

That gives

```
sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (24,26,27,28) have mixed types.Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
           0         1       2     3          4    5       6    7    8    9    10  ...        47      48 49                                50  51    52       53        54      55        56                                                 57
0  1095081749  20220412  202204  2022  2022.2795  NaN     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ... -119.7460      CA  2         California, United States  US  USCA  36.1700 -119.7460      CA  20230412  https://www.sandiegouniontribune.com/news/cali...
1  1095081750  20220412  202204  2022  2022.2795  NaN     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  -81.9059  294668  3  Bay Lake, Florida, United States  US  USFL  28.4775  -81.9059  294668  20230412  https://www.streetinsider.com/Reuters/New+Flor...
2  1095081751  20220412  202204  2022  2022.2795  NaN     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  -81.9059  294668  2            Florida, United States  US  USFL  27.8333  -81.7170      FL  20230412  https://www.streetinsider.com/Reuters/New+Flor...
3  1095081752  20220412  202204  2022  2022.2795  NaN     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  -81.7170      FL  2            Florida, United States  US  USFL  27.8333  -81.7170      FL  20230412  https://financialpost.com/pmn/business-pmn/new...
4  1095081753  20220412  202204  2022  2022.2795  COP  POLICE  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  -89.0022      IL  2           Illinois, United States  US  USIL  40.3363  -89.0022      IL  20230412  https://chicago.suntimes.com/crime/2023/4/11/2...

[5 rows x 58 columns]
```

Note the datatype errors reported in the output.